# Threaded drawing on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, multithreading, quartz-2d, nsoperation

Apples documentation states that in general Quartz2D is [thread-safe](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1238.html). However when drawing to an image context during a NSOperation I'm experiencing crashes (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

This is my current setup:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// drawing code
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I suspect the crashes are related to the current context as the UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext docu states that it needs to be called from the [main thread](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext). Is this correct? Are there any other ways to get the image context?

Comment: No it's not correct, the docs decided to lie to you for the sheer fun of it…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've answered your own question.  The docs say you have to call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() on the main thread, you're not doing so, and your app is crashing.  QED.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would be the correct way to do it? I'm currently looking into CGBitmapContextCreate.

Comment: The correct way to do this would be to break out UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext into a separate call you would run on the main thread, and store the graphics context into a class variable the other thread would make use of on return from the create.

Comment: @Kendall-Helmstetter-Gelner That would be an EXTREMELY bad idea. This is not an API designed for use from a background thread at all. Your suggestion leaves open some very gnarly race conditions

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to this question sooner. I'm now using CGBitmapContextCreate and it seems to have solved the problem for me. Not sure why I didn't come across this function earlier. Was probably looking for the wrong thing. 

Thank you everybody for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

The various UIGraphics functions are mostly just convenience methods around the lower-level functions. Read up CGGraphicsContext and how to create your own; the documentation is very helpful.